# Get data through GET request from API using x-www-form-urlencoded c#

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm using a post map to get my data using GET Method NOT POST. I send in the body value 1 and value 2

When I'm using the post man I used Body and x-www-form-urlencoded in Get request and the result in json format. I could succsfuly connect to the API but I could get the json data
here is the code :

```
var Parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(valu1, value2),
};

HttpClient httpClient_ = new HttpClient();

httpClient_.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
httpClient_.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");

var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ApiPath)
{
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Parameters)
};

var Result = httpClient_.SendAsync(Request).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Most of the answers are related to how send a POST request through the body and did not find any for GET. any help?

Comment: You do not send a GET.  The GET/POST are the body of a httprequest.  There are 5 steps 1) Client sends request with POST 2) Server receives request with GET 3) Server process request 4) Server sends response with POST 5) Client receive response with GET.

Comment: Generally speaking GET is not supposed to have a body content though the http protocol does not prohibited it. Common usage is that you use GET with Url parameters. What is your use case when you need use GET with body?